# How to manage states of a shared component where we want to retain the states based on the place the component is being used?

Tags: reactjs, state, mobx

For example: let's say we have a table component used on multiple pages or in a page multiple times. Now,  we want to maintain the selected items from the table for each table and highlight them.

So, currently, I am using an object to store the selected items based on the place it's being used:

```
{
  place1: {selectedItemId1: selectedItem1, selectedItemId2: selectedItem2},
  place2: {selectedItemId1: selectedItem1, selectedItemId2: selectedItem2},
  place3: {selectedItemId1: selectedItem1, selectedItemId2: selectedItem2}
}
```

Please let me know if you've any other better solution.

Comment: The table component itself could maintain the select state for its items.

Comment: I've used your approach a few times. Basically, you store that state object at, say, the App level or in a redux store. Presumably the 'place1', etc., are some sort of unique keys that identify the particular page on which the table appears. Of course, you can make this all neater via a custom hook.